# To Publish a Game

Tags: libgdx

I have a query that is if I want to publish a game that I created using **libgdx** and **android studio**. Do I have to pay the engine or studio to publish my desired game. Or Is it free? Regarding that my game is free and it has in app purchases.

Thank You.

Comment: How about you read the [license](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/LICENSE) and/or ask a lawyer?

Comment: @UnholySheep License as in libgdx license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to pay for [libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com) or [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) if you're using these for Game or App development.

After development you need to bring your application in market then you need pay some minimal charges for major application store like [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps) and [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8)

1. Google has a one time $25 registration fee which you need to pay before you can upload an app.

   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=en
2. And you have to pay 99$ per membership year for developers who enrolled as individuals for App Store.

   https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. Does it matter to all? Games and Apps.

Comment: I didn't get you ?

Comment: libGDX is licensed under [Apache 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License)

Comment: No it's okay. Thanks for the help. Can you explain the 99$ enrollment.

Comment: Are you individual developer or an organization ?

Comment: I am a developer.

Comment: If you're single person developer, you need to pay 99$ per membership year for distribution on the App Store.

Comment: Okay. And If I am not registered organisation? Just some guys. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Comment: Same 99$ If you’re with some guys, interested in creating apps for **distribution on the App Store**.

Comment: That if you're not using any paid libs or resources in your game, if you created everything you should be fine.